# Need a little help for algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, function

Right now I have a set of **if** and **elseif** to set the height of the div

```
<?php
if($num == 0){echo 'height:0px;';} 
elseif($num > 0 && $num < 10) {echo 'height:3px;';} 
elseif($num >= 10 && $num < 22) {echo 'height:7px;';}
elseif($num >= 22 && $num < 45) {echo 'height:16px;';}
elseif($num >= 45 && $num < 50) {echo 'height:33px;';}
elseif($num >= 50 && $num < 67) {echo 'height:36px;';}
elseif($num >= 67 && $num < 79) {echo 'height:48px;';}
elseif($num >= 79 && $num < 88) {echo 'height:56px;';}
elseif($num >= 88) {echo 'height:72px;';}
?>
```

The problem is that this is copyed 5 times for 5 different divs and think there is better way to do it

Like so :

```
<?php
      function divHeight($maxNum,$number)
{

    if($number == 0)
    {
      echo 'height:0px;' ;
    }

    elseif($number >= $maxNum)
    {
      echo 'height:72px;' ;
    }

    else
    {
       //here were the algorithm have to be
    }

}
```

?>

I will call it like `<?php divHeight(88,$number);?>`

The max height of div is 72, now how to calculate the height?

// Edit : This is so simple :X :X but is too late and i havent sleept so

```
$newHeight = floor($number * 72 / 100);

echo $newHeight;
```

Comment: your question is not clear. You want to optimize, make short your function ?

Comment: why not include the if conditions in your first code, into a function ? And call it whenever needed, by passing the number as parameter !

Comment: divHeight funciton is the new code I just needed a algorithm to calculate the height and the answer is $newHeight = floor($number * 72 / 100);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function mapNumToHeight($num) {
    // Max $num => height for that num
    $heightMap = array(
        0 => 0,
        9 => 3,
        21 => 7,
        44 => 16,
        49 => 33,
        66 => 36,
        78 => 48,
        87 => 56,
        88 => 72
    );

    // Store the keys into an array that we can search
    $keys = array_keys($heightMap);
    rsort($keys);

    // We want to find the smallest key that is greater than or equal to $num.
    $best_match = $keys[0];
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        if($key >= $num) {
            $best_match = $key;
        }
    }

    return 'height:' . $heightMap[$best_match] . 'px;';
}

mapNumToHeight(3); // height:3px;
mapNumToHeight(33); // height:16px;
mapNumToHeight(87); // height:56px;
mapNumToHeight(88); // height:72px;
mapNumToHeight(1000); // height:72px;
```

Comment: Lol this complicated .. I will vote it up since is interesting way of solving the problem. I solved with $newHeight = floor($number * 72 / 100);

Comment: `$number` = 59 -- `floor(59 * 72 / 100)` == 42. But your requirements state that for `$number` == 59, the result should be 36.

Comment: Yes but all if and elseif in the beging was the old code. I just simply define some heights, but the new code do it automatically. I guess because of the old code the question was missleading.

Comment: Indeed, your code can ever only be as good as your spec / requirements.